TypeError: root.markClean is not a function in nextjs
My next js was working as expected till I tried to do npm run build and npm run export, then the error started to appear whenever I tried to do npm run dev
Failed to compile

Next.js (14.2.7)
./src/@menu/styles/styles.module.css
TypeError: root.markClean is not a function

and here is how my ./src/@menu/styles/styles.module.css looks :
.ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}



At current time, this error seems to be related to postcss >= 8.4.42
look into the postcss issue tracker
8.4.43 should have fixed it, but it still persist for me with nextjs 14.2.7.
You can downgrade to postcss 8.4.41 for a temporary fix and wait for a bugfix.
 npm install postcss@8.4.41


You are running the commands in the wrong order:

npm run build - generate the build in .next
npm run export - generate a static export
npm run dev - run the dev preview

You can't run a dev preview on a production build. Instead change the order of commands to:

npm run build - generate the build in .next
npm run export - generate a static export
npm run start - run the production preview

